# pandas timeseries select single date

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, time-series

Selecting a single date from a timeserie gives a KeyError.

Setup:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
ts = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range(start = '1/1/2017', periods = 5),
                   'observations': np.random.choice(range(0, 100), 5, replace = True)}).set_index('date')
```

Dataframe:

```
           observations
date                    
2017-01-01            58
2017-01-02            88
2017-01-03            53
2017-01-04             4
2017-01-05            26
```

How do I select the number of observations for a single date?

```
ts['2017-01-01']
```

Returns: KeyError: '2017-01-01'

But...

```
ts['2017-01-01':'2017-01-01']
```

...seems to work just fine.

Any suggestions how to select/subset with a single date?

Comment: have you tried `ts.loc['2017-01-01']`?

Comment: Directly indexing a dataframe references its columns, not its rows. @Ben.T's solution provides the typical way to index rows instead

Comment: @Ben.T could you quickly write that answer so Rene can mark it as correct for pointing out the bug?

Comment: Thanks, works fine! And thanks for the clear explanation. But it still feels a bit 'inconsistent' in pandas.

Comment: @Rene at the beginning, especially if you come from numpy, I understand your feeling. But after a bit, I end up to be more often operations between columns than between rows and looking for column's name this way is easy :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As **@scnerd** pointed out, when you do `ts['2017-01-01']` it tries to find '2017-01-01' as a column's name of the dataframe `ts`, which gives you an `KeyError` as none of the columns in `ts` has this name

In order to look for an index' name, as in your example 'date' is set as index, you need to use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) method such as `ts.loc['2017-01-01']` and you will get:

```
observations    54
Name: 2017-01-01 00:00:00, dtype: int32
```